# Modulo of division of modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to re-phrase this calculation to something aesthetically more appealing?

```
int seconds = [0-86400];
int number = ((seconds % 3600)/60)%60;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ?. Please also explain that.

Comment: What is the $/$ operator? Integer division? If it's ordinary rational division, then it makes no sense to take the resulting number mod 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is shorter and equivalent:

```
int number = (seconds / 60) % 60;
```

or this one, if you prefer:

```
int number = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
```